# user customize theme color by color picker

Tags: php, html, css

I Want to let clients to change the background-color for some parts of the template.

1. Is this a good concept to take their selected color values and set them by inline styling for html tags using PHP code or not?
2. some parts have just 3 or 4 or specific number of  color values which can use the prepared classes that have their color values.In this way classes will use instead of inline styling codes.
   Is my 1st method good enough or not?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set theme colors according to user preferences then, rather than using PHP to write the styles inline inside each element, I would opt for **CSS Custom Properties** and use PHP to write the values of those Custom Properties dynamically into the `<head>` of the document.

For example, if in the `<head>` of your document, you have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
```

and in your `styles.css` stylesheet you have:

```
h1 {
  color: var(--theme-color-1);
  background-color: var(--theme-color-3);
}

h2 {
  color: var(--theme-color-2);
  background-color: var(--theme-color-3);
}

p {
  color: var(--theme-color-4);
}
```

Then, immediately beneath your `<link rel="stylesheet">` you can use **PHP** to add a second stylesheet, confirming the values of the custom properties you have referred to in your main stylesheet:

```
echo '
<style>
  :root {
    --theme-color-1: '.$Theme_Color_1.'
    --theme-color-2: '.$Theme_Color_2.'
    --theme-color-3: '.$Theme_Color_3.'
    --theme-color-4: '.$Theme_Color_4.'
  }
</style>
';
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties
- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/04/start-using-css-custom-properties/